# MVVM. Установить данные

Tags: android, mvvm

Нужно положить данные в LiveData, чтобы отправить в колбек. В этом методе:

```
    public void setData(List<Data> data) {
    this.currentData.setValue((Data) data);
}
```

по документации setValue вызывается у MutableLiveData, я заменила во ViewModel LiveData на MutableLiveData, но все равно при открытии нужного фрагмента приложение падает с ошибкой

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData cannot be cast to androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
    at avocado.droid.ptitsami.room.DataViewModel.<init>(DataViewModel.java:24)
    at avocado.droid.ptitsami.room.DataViewModel$ModelFactory.create(DataViewModel.java:54)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$FactoryWrapper.create(ViewModelProvider.java:268)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:179)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:147)
    at avocado.droid.ptitsami.fragment.DataFragment.onCreateView(DataFragment.java:57)
```

Как это исправить?

ViewModel

```
public class DataViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
MutableLiveData<Data> currentData;
DataRepository repository;


public DataViewModel(@NonNull Application application, final int verseId) {
    super(application);
    int verseId1 = verseId;
    repository = new DataRepository(application);
    currentData = (MutableLiveData<Data>) repository.getById(verseId);
}

public LiveData<Data> getById() {
    return currentData;
}

public void setData(List<Data> data) {
    this.currentData.setValue((Data) data);
}


public static class ModelFactory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {

    @NonNull
    private final Application application;
    private final int dataId;
    private final DataRepository repository;

    public ModelFactory(@NonNull Application application, int id) {
        super();
        this.application = application;
        this.dataId = id;
        repository = new DataRepository(application);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        if (modelClass == DataViewModel.class) {
            return (T) new DataViewModel(application, dataId);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Fragment

```
public class DataFragment extends Fragment {
private int dataId;
private static final String KEY_DATA_ID = "KEY_DATA_ID";
public TextView tvTitle;

public DataFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootViewRead = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_data, container, false);
    Toolbar toolbar = rootViewRead.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    if (activity != null) {
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    tvTitle = (TextView) rootViewRead.findViewById(R.id.text);

    DataViewModel.ModelFactory factory = new DataViewModel.ModelFactory(
            getActivity().getApplication(), getArguments().getInt(KEY_DATA_ID));

    final DataViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory)
            .get(DataViewModel.class);
    model.getById().observe(this, new Observer<Data>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Data data) {
           model.setData((List<Data>) data);

        }
    });

    return rootViewRead;
}

public static DataFragment forData(int dataId) {
    DataFragment fragment = new DataFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(KEY_DATA_ID, dataId);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

repository

```
public class DataRepository {
private DatabaseCopier db;

DataRepository(Application application) {
    db = DatabaseCopier.getInstance(application);
}

LiveData<Data> getById(int id) {
    return db.getDatabase().dataDao().getById(id);
}
```

Comment: Зачем во фрагменте вы делаете `observe`и в нем пытаетесь установить какие то данные?

Comment: Этот фрагмент открывается при клике на айтем списка другого фрагмента и должен отражать подробное описание. В примерах от гугла нашла похожую реализацию, но не могу до конца разобраться. Буду благодарна если подскажите как правильно делать

Comment: В методе observe вам придет Data с бд. Можете ее отобразить на экране. Или что то другое нужно?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду сразу выполнить tvTitle.setText?

Comment: да, берете ваш объект, который почему то кастится вот `(List<Data>) datа`. Вы можете из рума возвращать сразу `LiveData<List<Data>>`

Comment: переделала по вашему совету метод onChanged - tvTitle.setText(data.getTitle()); все равно не работает. ошибка  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String .room.Data.getTitle()' on a null object reference

Comment: Это потому что Data равна null. Проверьте, что из бд возвращается Data, а не что-то другое

Comment: Нашла ошибку. А ваш совет мне помог, можете оформить - отмечу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильным подходом будет сделать `LiveData` полем во `ViewModel` и сделать `observe` во фрагменте, если мы хотим изменить данные, то мы вставляем в их нашу бд и тогда изменения автоматически придут в `observe`

`MutableLiveData` была бы нужна, если мы не сохраняли данные в рум. Тогда мы могли бы сделать `observe` на такую лайвдату и где-нибудь в коде`setValue` и новые данные приходили бы в observe.

Главное не делать setValue в observe, потому что тогда у нас будет цикличность